# Deployment of mahout on Google app engine (java)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I want to ask about deployment of mahout on Google app engine.

I have mahout-core-0.8-javadoc.jar ,

So Is it possible to deploy mahout recommendation system algorithm on Google apps engine?

On the Eclipse for java,and I will combine with android.

If it can, then how can we deploy?

Thanks .

Comment: This post should be moved to android.stackexchange.com.

Comment: So I can go to android.stackexchange.com to find my answer ?

Comment: Unless there's coding involved, then StackOverflow will be the correct forum for this sort of question. If it's just a software installation / integration type of questions, then yes, the other forum is better for you.